# C++ Templates vs OOD woes - How can I get around implementing something like 'templated class member variables'?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Im trying to save a lot of code duplication using templates.
Ideally I would like to do something along the lines of this (I know its garbage code):

```
class Registries {
public:

    template<typename T>
    void AddToRegistry(T thing) {
        registry.push_back(thing);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>* GetRegistry<T>() {
        return &registry();
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> registry; // auto-magically created vectors for each used type
};


int main() {
    Registries registries;

    CoolThing thing1;
    NiceThing thing2;
    // ... Many N types

    registries.AddToRegistry(thing1);
    registries.AddToRegistry(thing2);

    std::vector<CoolThing>* cool_registry = registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>();
    std::vector<NiceThing>* nice_registry = registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>();
}
```

It of course doesnt work because I can't template a class member - a variable won't be created for each type, and these functions wouldnt know what one to return):

I could do this, but they'll all be stored in static memory (not ideal):

```
class CoolThing {
public:
    static std::vector<CoolThing> registry;
};

class NiceThing {
public:
    static std::vector<NiceThing> registry;
};

class Registries {
public:

    template<typename T>
    void AddToRegistry(T thing) {
        T::registry.push_back(thing);
    }
}


int main() {
    Registries registries;

    registries.AddToRegistry(CoolThing());
    registries.AddToRegistry(NiceThing());
    // ... Many N types
}
```

I also tried switch and if-else within a template but they seem incompatible:

```
class CoolThing {
public:
    const static ThingType TYPE = COOL;
};

class NiceThing {
public:
    const static ThingType TYPE = NICE;
};

class Registries {
public:

    template<typename T>
    void AddToRegistry(T thing) {

        switch (T::TYPE) {
        
        case ThingType::COOL:
            cool_registry.push_back(thing);
            return;

        case ThingType::NICE:
            nice_registry.push_back(thing);
            return;
        
        default:
            return;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>* GetRegistry<T>() {
        
        if (T::TYPE == ThingType::COOL) {

            return &cool_registry;
        } 
        else if (T::TYPE == ThingType::NICE) {

            return &nice_registry;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::vector<CoolThing> cool_registry;
    std::vector<NiceThing> nice_registry;
    // ... Many N types
};


int main() {
    Registries registries;

    CoolThing thing1;
    NiceThing thing2;
    // ... Many N types

    registries.AddToRegistry(thing1);
    registries.AddToRegistry(thing2);

    std::vector<CoolThing>* = registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>();
    std::vector<NiceThing>* = registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>();
}
```

I feel like my options are the static way, or writing a long list of (20+ types) function overloads to add to the correct registry type.

Any template whizzes out there know an alternative?
Many thanks

Comment: Have you thought in using a ```std::vector``` containing ```std::variant```? It is a nice solution if you have a limited number of classes. The other way (the old pre c++11 way) should be polymorphism, declaring an Interface, an abstract base class used as heritage for your other classes.

Comment: Why are you templating individual functions instead of the entire class?  A template class can easily have members of the template type.

Comment: *"Any template whizzes out there know an alternative?"* Yes, I invented an approach that uses `std::any` and `std::map` to do the same. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xq7x4v3cY) as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77431357/12002570).

Comment: @Pablo I wouldn't want a vector of variants as I want to pack the same types tightly together so i can iterate fast over them. I thought about polymorphism too, but id rather avoid that performance hit if possible

Comment: @InquiryOrEnquiry See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77431357/12002570) which avoid both polymorphism and code duplication.

Comment: @Mark Ransom The class is a container of containers of many different types

Comment: *I also tried switch and if-else within a template but they seem incompatible.* Use [constexpr-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution that does not rely on runtime type erasure (`std::any`) or global singletons would be to store a tuple of `std::vector<T>`:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename... Ts>
class Registries {
public:

    template<typename T>
    void AddToRegistry(T thing) {
        GetRegistry<T>().push_back(thing);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& GetRegistry() {
        return std::get<std::vector<T>>(registry);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> registry;
};

struct CoolThing {};
struct NiceThing {};


int main() {
    Registries<CoolThing, NiceThing> registries;

    CoolThing thing1;
    NiceThing thing2;
    // ... Many N types

    registries.AddToRegistry(thing1);
    registries.AddToRegistry(thing2);

    std::vector<CoolThing>& cool_registry = registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>();
    std::vector<NiceThing>& nice_registry = registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>();
}
```

Note that this requires you to know all possible types when instantiating the registry.

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8M7MPxTd9)

PS: If that bothers you, here is a solution with type erasure that does not have this restriction: https://godbolt.org/z/nvWchfMaK

Comment: Another elegant solution! I think i will use this - its simple, with fewer libraries and minimal overhead. I know all the types at compile time so this is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First version would work fine if you fix incorrect syntax and if you're ok with an idea of singleton (i.e. global) `registries`.

```
#include <vector>

struct CoolThing {};
struct NiceThing {};

class Registries {
public:

    template<typename T>
    void AddToRegistry(T thing) {
        registry<T>.push_back(thing);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>* GetRegistry() {
        return &registry<T>;
    }

private:
    template<typename T>  
    static std::vector<T> registry; // template of static member variable
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Registries::registry = {}; 

int main() {
    Registries registries;

    CoolThing thing1;
    NiceThing thing2;
    // ... Many N types

    registries.AddToRegistry(thing1);
    registries.AddToRegistry(thing2);

    std::vector<CoolThing>* cool_registry = registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>();
    std::vector<NiceThing>* nice_registry = registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>();
}
```

Otherwise you would need mix factory method with a proxy pattern and create such container ad-hoc if such didn't exist yet, not as a member of `Registry` class.

Answer (score 0):

> Any template whizzes out there know an alternative? I feel like my options are the static way, or **writing a long list of (20+ types) function overloads** to add to the correct registry type

No you don't need to write so many overloads when you can just generalize this by using [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and **minimize code duplication** as shown below.

Here we first create a `std::map` which maps *Things*(`CoolThing` and `NiceThing` in your example) to their respective registries(`cool_registry` and `nice_registry`).

```
class CoolThing{};
class NiceThing{};

class Registries {
public:

    
    template<typename T> void AddToRegistry(T Arg)
    {
        std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<T>>>(myMap.at(typeid(T))).get().push_back(Arg);
    }

    template<typename T> std::vector<T>* GetRegistry() {
        return &(std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<T>>>(myMap.at(typeid(T))).get());
    } 

private:
    std::vector<CoolThing> cool_registry;
    std::vector<NiceThing> nice_registry;

    //create std::map 
    std::map<std::type_index, std::any> myMap{{typeid(CoolThing), std::ref(cool_registry)}, 
                                                  {typeid(NiceThing), std::ref(nice_registry)}};
};

int main()
{
    //let's create some instances to push back into the vectors 
    CoolThing C1;
    CoolThing C2;
    
    NiceThing N1;
    NiceThing N2;
    NiceThing N3;

    Registries registries;
    
    //lets add the instances using the member function template
    registries.AddToRegistry(C1); 
    //lets confirm if the entity was added correctly into the vector 
    std::cout << "Size of cool_registry: " << (*registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>()).size(); //prints 1 as expected
    std::cout << "\nSize of nice_registry: " << (*registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>()).size(); //prints 0 as expected

    //lets add some more instances
    registries.AddToRegistry(C2);
    registries.AddToRegistry(N1);
    registries.AddToRegistry(N2);
    registries.AddToRegistry(N3); 

    //lets confirm if the entity was added correctly into the vector 
    std::cout << "\nSize of cool_registry: " << (*registries.GetRegistry<CoolThing>()).size(); //prints 2 as expected
    std::cout << "\nSize of nice_registry: " << (*registries.GetRegistry<NiceThing>()).size(); //prints 3 as expected
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xq7x4v3cY)

Comment: Thats awesome! I think this might just be it, thank you! Ill get myself familiar with these types. Its a bit like the switch/if-else version except this seems to compile.

Comment: @InquiryOrEnquiry  You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

What you're most likely looking for is template specialization. You can define behaviour for specific type cases on templated definitions.

```
class Regs {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void AddRegister(T t) { ... } // Generic Case
        
        template<>
        void AddRegister<CoolThing>(CoolThing ct) { ... } // When T is CoolThing

        template<>
        void AddRegister<NiceThing>(NiceThing nt) { ... } // When T is NiceThing
};
```

Alternatively, since overloading can become very verbose, you could use a map map type_info to function pointer or something similar, tho that'll require all cases to be known at compile-time